# Du müsstest keine Angst haben

Tags: modal-verb

Google translates *Du müsstest keine Angst haben*  to

> You should not be afraid.

Is it a correct translation?

How come that *müssen* is not translated as *must*?

Comment: For me, it looks okay, but it is not the English Language SE :-)

Comment: Google says this, deepL something else: https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Du%20m%C3%BCsstest%20keine%20Angst%20haben -->  Don't trust automatic translations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negation of must works different in English and German. In English the "not" negates the action, so "you must do X" means "you are requested to do X!" and "you must not do X" means "you are requested not to do X".
In German, however, the "not" negates the "must", so "Du musst X nicht tun" means "you are not requested to do X" or "you needn't do X".

Comment: I don't feel this answers the question and it even contains wrong information. *Must not* means *not allowed to*. The correct negation would be *not to have to*.

Answer (score 4):

Here we have *müssen* in Konjunktiv II. (Indicative preterite would be "Du musstest keine Angst haben" - note the [missing] umlaut)

*Müssen* in Konjunktiv II usually translates to "should" in English.

For example:

> Das müsste funktionieren.

*This should work.*